# Derivatives of inverse functions

Tags: derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

f(x)=x-tanx

I am supposed to find the derivative to the inverse function in $(\pi$/4)$-1$.
So my plan was to use the formula for the derivative of the inverse function. I have defined the domain to f(x) as $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, to make it a one-to-one function. But I'm not able to solve this equation

x-tanx=$(\pi/4)-1$

Could someone help me?

Comment: The solution to your equation is $x=\pi/4$.

Comment: @A.Goodier Oh, thank you! But how did you solve it by the way?

Comment: Just by noticing that $\tan(\pi/4)=1$, so we have $x-\tan x=\pi/4-\tan(\pi/4)$. In questions like this, the point at which you have to find the derivative is often a nice value.

Comment: @A.Goodier Ohhh, of course. By the way, I just wonder if I'm thinking right when it comes to solving this task?

Comment: Yes, now you just need to use the formula for the derivative in the answer below, with $g(x_0)=\pi/4$.

Comment: @A.Goodier. Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that if $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, at $x=x_0$ we have:

$$g'(x_0)=\frac1{f'(g(x_0))}$$

with $g(x_0)=\pi/4$ indeed $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$ and thus

$$f(\pi/4)=\pi/4-1\implies g(f(\pi/4))=\pi/4=g(\pi/4-1)$$

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I have to find out what g(x0) is. And to do so, I have to solve the equation above right?

Comment: Yes we need to assume $g(x_0)=\pi/4$.

Comment: Indeed we have that $$f(\pi/4)=\pi/4-1 \implies g(f(\pi/4))=\pi/4=g(\pi/4-1)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!